# Filter angular js data source inside parent and child nodes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have created a tree view in `angular js` using `ng-repeat`. I have also added a filter to filter my data source. I am able to filter the parent nodes and the resource nodes as what I expected, but my problem is I could not achieve the child node filtering as I expected. This is the picture of my current development status.

[image]

Img 4 Shows the current ststus of filtering my child nodes, but my exact requirement is like that in Img 5. i.e, on filtering a node if there is a child node present, only that child node and its parent should apperar, all the remaining child nodes must be hidden. What should I do for that. Here is my code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("app", [])
            .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
                $scope.ObjectData = { "name": "Main Object 1",
                                      "ParentObject": [
                                        {
                                          "name": "Parent Object 1",
                                          "ChildObject": [
                                            {"name": "Child Object 11"},
                                            {"name": "Child Object 12"}
                                          ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "name": "Parent Object 2",
                                          "ChildObject": [
                                            {"name": "Child Object 21"},
                                            {"name": "Child Object 22"}
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      ],
                                      "resources": [
                                        "Resource 1", "Resource 2"
                                      ]
                                    }
            });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search" ng-model="search">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span>{{ ObjectData.name }}</span>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="subItem in ObjectData.ParentObject | filter:search">
                        <a>
                            <span>{{ subItem.name }}</span>
                        </a>

                        <ul>
                            <li ng-repeat="childItem in subItem.ChildObject">
                                <a>
                                    <span>{{ childItem.name }}</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="resources in ObjectData.resources | filter:search">
                        <a>
                            <span>{{ resources }}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting some more effort, I just created a simple logic to implement my requirement. I'm posting the solution because this might be helpful for someone.

I just added an `ng-if` inside my child item div. It displays the div content based on two condition.

> 1. The individual child object should be visible if the search key contains the characters inside the div.
> 2. All the child elements must be visible if the search key consists of the characters in the parent node.

Here is my final code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("app", [])
            .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
                $scope.ObjectData = { "name": "Main Object 1",
                                      "ParentObject": [
                                        {
                                          "name": "Parent Object 1",
                                          "ChildObject": [
                                            {"name": "Child Object 11"},
                                            {"name": "Child Object 12"}
                                          ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "name": "Parent Object 2",
                                          "ChildObject": [
                                            {"name": "Child Object 21"},
                                            {"name": "Child Object 22"}
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      ],
                                      "resources": [
                                        "Resource 1", "Resource 2"
                                      ]
                                    };
                $scope.IsChildObjectVisible = function(parent, child){
                    var searchKey = $scope.search;
                    var returnVal = true;
                    if(undefined != searchKey && null != searchKey && searchKey.length > 0){                        
                        returnVal = ((child.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) > -1) || //Search key is present in a child node then that node is visible
                                     (parent.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) > -1)); //Search key is present in the parent node so all the child nodes inside that are visible
                    }
                    return returnVal;
                }
            });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search" ng-model="search">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a><span>{{ ObjectData.name }}</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="subItem in ObjectData.ParentObject | filter:search">
                        <a><span>{{ subItem.name }}</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li ng-repeat="childItem in subItem.ChildObject" ng-if="IsChildObjectVisible(subItem, childItem)">
                                <a><span>{{ childItem.name }}</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="resources in ObjectData.resources | filter:search">
                        <a><span>{{ resources }}</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="childItem in subItem.ChildObject" ng-if='$filter(subItem.ChildObject, search).length == 0 || childItem.name == search'>
    <a>
        <span>{{ childItem.name }}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**Javascript:**

```
.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.$filter = $filter('filter');
    //other stuff...
});
```